# java inheritance within one class, deploy variables to two functions

Tags: java, inheritance, coding-style

How can I make the variables I define at the top of this class apply to both of the functions within?

specifically dict and url.

Right now eclipse is telling me, with regards to `dict.open()` that an "identifier is expected after it", but I think this is a red herring because if I move it back inside the `getHypernyms` method it will work again. I could just copy that code into both methods but that's so stupid and such bad style. There must be a more elegant way to achieve that.

```
public class MITJavaWordNetInterface 
{

// construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
String wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
String path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
URL url = new URL ("file", null , path );

// construct the dictionary object and open it
IDictionary dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
dict.open();


public void getHypernyms( String inut_word ) throws IOException
{   

    // get the synset of 'input_word'
    IIndexWord idxWord = dict . getIndexWord (inut_word, POS . NOUN ) ;
    IWordID wordID = idxWord . getWordIDs () . get (0) ; // 1st meaning
    IWord word = dict . getWord ( wordID ) ;
    ISynset synset = word . getSynset () ;

    // get the hypernyms
    List < ISynsetID > hypernyms =
    synset . getRelatedSynsets ( Pointer . HYPERNYM ) ;

    // print out each h y p e r n y m s id and synonyms
    List < IWord > words ;
    for( ISynsetID sid : hypernyms ) {
    words = dict . getSynset ( sid ) . getWords () ;
    System . out . print ( sid + " {") ;
    for( Iterator < IWord > i = words . iterator () ; i . hasNext () ;) {
    System . out . print ( i . next () . getLemma () ) ;
    if( i . hasNext () )
    System . out . print (", ") ;
    }
    System . out . println ("}") ;
    }


}

public void getStem (String word)
{
 //JWS ws = new JWS("C:/Program Files/WordNet","2.1");  
 WordnetStemmer stem =  new WordnetStemmer( dict );
 System.out.println("test" + stem.findStems(word, null) );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow `MITJavaWordNetInterface` objects, you should create a **constructor** and do your initializations here:

```
public class MITJavaWordNetInterface 
{
    String wnhome;
    String path;
    URL url;

    IDictionary dict;

    public MITJavaWordNetInterface() {
        wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
        path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
        url = new URL ("file", null, path);
        dict = new Dictionary(url) ;
        dict.open();
    }

    public void getHypernyms(String inut_word) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

    public void getStem(String word) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MITJavaWordNetInterface m = new MITJavaWordNetInterface();
    m.getHypernyms(...);
    m.getStem(...);
}
```

Otherwise, create a **static constructor** in which to do your initializations:

```
public class MITJavaWordNetInterface 
{
    static String wnhome;
    static String path;
    static URL url;

    static IDictionary dict;

    static {
        wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
        path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
        url = new URL ("file", null, path);
        dict = new Dictionary(url) ;
        dict.open();
    }

    public static void getHypernyms(String inut_word) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

    public static void getStem(String word) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MITJavaWordNetInterface.getHypernyms(...);
    MITJavaWordNetInterface.getStem(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict.open();` is not in any method or [*constructor*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), and every statement (there are some exceptions with initializations of variables) must be in a method in java.

You should create a constructor for your object, and initialize `dict` in it:

```
public class  MITJavaWordNetInterface  {
   //I added private modifier for variables, remove if they're not private
   private String wnhome
   private String path
   private URL url;
   private IDictionary dict;

   //Here is an argumentless constructor:   
   public MITJavaWordNetInterface() { 
       // construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
       wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
       path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
       url = new URL ("file", null , path );
       // construct the dictionary object and open it
      dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
      dict.open();
   }
   ///methods
}
```

Comment: so create a method with the same name as the class?

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō "Method with same name as the class" - this is not a method, this is a constructor, note there is no return type there, and indeed the name of the "method" is the name of the class - this is a constructor, that is invoked every time an object of this type is created

Comment: hmm, seems it worked. can you please explain me why that is the necessary

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō I did in the beginning of the answer, you placed a *statement* `dict.open();` not in any method - java doesn't "know" when to do this statement, and thus gave you a compilation error